# Deleting an element form vector of type structure

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I am trying this piece of code where I want to delete an element from the vector of type structure

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _list
{
    int x;
}list;

std::vector<list> v;
list li[5];

void PushElements()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        li[i].x = i+2;
        v.push_back(li[i]);
    }
}

void display()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].x << endl;
    }
}

bool test()
{
    int flag = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(li[i].x < 3)
             flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}

void DeleteElement()
{
    v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), test), v.end());
}

int main()
{
    PushElements();
    display();
    DeleteElement();

    return 0;
}
```

But while compiling I get the foolowing error:

```
 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(1241) : error C2197: 'bool (__cdecl *)(void)' : too many arguments for call
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(4951) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Remove_copy_if<std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,_OutIt,bool(__cdecl *)(void)>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Pr,std::_Range_checked_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<list,std::allocator<list>>,
1>            _Ty=list,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<list>,
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<list,std::allocator<list>>,
1>            _Pr=bool (__cdecl *)(void)
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio    9.0\vc\include\algorithm(1311) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt stdext::unchecked_remove_copy_if<std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>,_FwdIt,bool(__cdecl *)(void)>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<list,std::allocator<list>>,
1>            _Ty=list,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<list>,
1>            _FwdIt=std::_Vector_iterator<list,std::allocator<list>>,
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<list,std::allocator<list>>,
1>            _Pr=bool (__cdecl *)(void)
1>        ]
```

I am not able to understand what this error is and how to solve?
Can somebody help me in solving this error??

Comment: Read e.g. [this `std::remove_if` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Pay special attention to the predicate (the function you pass), and how it should be declared and how it is used.

Comment: All identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved for use (by the implementation) as names in the global namespace. Your name for the struct (`_list`) is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) expects the signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to

```
bool pred(const Type &a);
```

But `bool test()` doesn't take any parameter, it doesn't match. You might want

```
bool test(const list& v)
{
    // judgement process based on the individual element passed
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was very confused the author want to do.if you want to a program to add or remove some number you may erase many lines;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _list
{
    int x;
  _list(int x)
    {
        this->x=x;
    }
}list;

std::vector<list> v;
void PushElements()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        v.push_back(list(i+2));//the number you want to add
    }
}
void display()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i].x << "\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

bool test(list &a)
{

    return a.x>3;
}

void DeleteElement()
{
    v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), test), v.end());
}

int main()
{
    PushElements();
    display();
    DeleteElement();
     display();
    return 0;
}
```